# Postfix Server - How do I block an IP thats is constantly trying to connect

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot, fail2ban, iredmail

Firstly, thanks for looking.
I have recently set up a postfix mailserver with dovecot using the following guide:
https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/ubuntu-18-04-iredmail-email-server

I have been monitoring the logs on /var/log/mail.log and the following entry keep showing every minute:

> May 12 14:09:47 mail postfix/postscreen[32610]: CONNECT from [102.68.24.27]:59165 to [MYIP ADDRESS]:25
> May 12 14:09:47 mail postfix/postscreen[32610]: PASS OLD [102.68.24.27]:59165
> May 12 14:09:47 mail postfix/smtpd[32613]: warning: hostname yourcommunications.co.za does not resolve to address 102.68.24.27
> May 12 14:09:47 mail postfix/smtpd[32613]: connect from unknown[102.68.24.27]
> May 12 14:09:47 mail postfix/smtpd[32613]: lost connection after EHLO from unknown[102.68.24.27]
> May 12 14:09:47 mail postfix/smtpd[32613]: disconnect from unknown[102.68.24.27] ehlo=1 commands=1

Please could someone help me block this ip from connecting?

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 using iredmail 1.4.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `fail2ban-client status` ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at these postfix anvil parameters:

`anvil_rate_time_unit (default: 60s)`:
The time unit over which client connection rates and other rates are calculated.

`anvil_status_update_time (default: 600s)`:
How frequently the anvil(8) connection and rate limiting server logs peak usage information.

`smtpd_client_connection_count_limit (default: 50)`:
The maximum number of connections that an SMTP client may make simultaneously.

`smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit (default: no limit)`:
The maximum number of connections that an SMTP client may make in the time interval specified with `anvil_rate_time_unit (default: 60s)`.

`smtpd_client_message_rate_limit (default: no limit)`:
The maximum number of message delivery requests that an SMTP client may make in the time interval specified with `anvil_rate_time_unit (default: 60s)`.

`smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit (default: no limit)`:
The maximum number of recipient addresses that an SMTP client may specify in the time interval specified with `anvil_rate_time_unit (default: 60s)`.